# Database exception not being caught in try/catch in c#

Tags: c#, database, db2, odbc, database-connection

I'm working with a DB2 database using an OdbcConnection in c#. I have never seen a sql exception thrown by the database never get caught, but sure enough, I've now run into this occurrence. My statements to open & close the connection work fine according to my print statements. I'm surrounding the code in a try/catch and am writting to the log file at various points in the try/catch body as well as in the exception body. My log statements in the exception body are never written...by all accounts from my logging, the database insert went fine...only it didn't as far as DB2 is concerned.

Here is an interesting part of the trace I'm seeing:

> [1380564032.174591 - 09/30/2013 13:00:32.174591] ( Unretrieved error
>   message="[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0407N  Assignment of a NULL
>   value to a NOT NULL column "TBSPACEID=2, TABLEID=4, COLNO=7" is not
>   allowed.  SQLSTATE=23502
>
> " ) [1380564032.186504 - 09/30/2013 13:00:32.186504]

I was initially using ExecuteScalar. I've tried ExecuteNonQuery & ExecuteReader. All have the same error and this same issue with the error not being caught in the try/catch.

Thoughts?

**EDIT 1**

Here's the code:

```
public void InsertRecord(MyObject entry)
{
    try
    {

        OpenConnection();

        // Prep command object.             
        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(Queries.InsertRecord, this.odbcCn))
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 30;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            //Force error testing
            entry.Zip = "9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999";

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@ZIP", ntry.Zip));

            object o = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);

            int id = -1;

            LogUtil.WriteCondensed("Insert to db succeeded. Id: " + id.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (OdbcException e)
    {
        LogUtil.Write("INSERT ROW", "Exception occurred");
        CloseConnection();
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogUtil.Write("INSERT ROW","Exception occurred");
        CloseConnection();
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseConnection();
    }

    return ;
}
```

Comment: "I'm surrounding the code in a try/catch"- please show us all relevant code.

Comment: See the documention http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx for ExecuteNonQuery, which is what you should be using.  Please show us your code so we have an idea of what could be going wrong.  A lot of people catch SQLException instead of all exceptions.  If your exception types don't match what is thrown, your catch will fail.

Comment: Updated the post with the code. Thanks for the input.

Comment: You can remove the `catch (OdbcException e)`, since `catch (Exception e)` has the same code. Also, remove `CloseConnection();` from the `catch (Exception e)` block, since `CloseConnection();` will always be called in the `finally` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here:

[DB connection InfoMessage callback not firing immediately for stored proc print statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071390/db-connection-infomessage-callback-not-firing-immediately-for-stored-proc-print)

I'm not having the issues the person posting the question was. I just had to provide a handler for the InfoMessage delegate. My handler looks like:

```
    private static void OnInfoMessage(Object sender, OdbcInfoMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (args != null && args.Errors != null &&
            args.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (OdbcError error in args.Errors)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(error.Message);
            }

            LogUtil.WriteException("InsertRow", new Exception(sb.ToString()));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Message))
        {
            LogUtil.Write("InsertRow", args.Message);
        }

    }
```

Thanks for your input, everyone. Is there anything you'd like to add? Note that I'm using ExecuteReader on the insert statement, but the error isn't being thrown natively without giving the connection delegate this handler. thoughts?